# Extract results from Twitter search to csv or excel

Tags: excel, search, twitter, extract

I'm trying to extract the results from a Twitter search to an excel file or csv but don't know exactly how I could do that. I found https://scraperwiki.com/ that can supposedly do this but they're having trouble with their Twitter api access. I've read things about a python script I could use but lots seems to be outdated and through Twitter changes can't be used anymore. Is this currently do-able?

Comment: Have you tried using the official search API? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Comment: That's the plan. But I'm not sure which kind of python script would work. And since I'm only a beginner with python I don't think I know enough to write my own script